# Angular - merge multiple consecutive API calls into one result

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm in the process of learning rxjs and currently facing something I'm not quite sure how to tackle. I need to call multiple API requests, but the issue is that first I need to get a list of names, and then, for each name get the rest of the data. So far I've come up with two `map` functions, the first call will get list of names, and the second `map` will iterate over the list and call another request to get the rest of the data. I assume this is bad practice but I cannot understand how to use `mergeMap` or `forkjoin` to achieve a better functioning code.

```
  public getNames(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<response>(someUrl)
                          .pipe(map(res => res.results), map((data)=>{
                              data.forEach(dat => {
                               this.getDataByName(dat.name).subscribe(res => {
                                  dat.image = res.image;
                               });
                              });
                              return data;
                            }));
  }
  
  public getDataByName(name): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(urlToGetMoreDataByName)
                          .pipe(map(res => res.results));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right your problem, I would try something along these lines

```
// remove the specification of the return type (: Observable<any>) since you
// should be able to achieve a more precise result using Typescript 
// type inference
    
public getNames() {
  return this.httpClient.get<response>(someUrl).pipe(
        map(res => res.results),
        // transform "data", which is an array of names in an array of Observables
        // this first map is the rxjs map operator
        map((data)=> {
           // this inner map is the javascript method of the array
           // for each dat it returns an Observable which emits when getDataByNme returns
           return data.map(dat => this.getDataByName(dat.name).pipe(
                                    // this is an rxjs map operator which retuns a
                                    // dat object with the image property set
                                     map(res => {
                                       dat.image = res.image;
                                       return dat
                                     })
                                  )
           )
       }),
       // concatMap is used here to make sure that we fire the execution of the 
       // Observable created by forkJoin after the first get operation has returned
       concatMap(arrayOfObservables => forkJoin(arrayOfObservables))
     );
}
```

Now `getNames` returns an Observable which emits once all the calls to fetch the images have been executed. Using `forkJoin` we make sure we launch all the http get operations in parallel. We could use other operators, e.g. `mergeMap, if we wanted to control the concurrency level.

You may find some inspiration about which operators can be possibly used with http operations [in this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.campaignService.getCampaignDetailById(this.data.campaignId).subscribe((response: any) => {
      if (response && response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
        this.campaignService.getCampaignSessionDetailById(response.data[0].session_id).subscribe((response: any) => {
          if (response && response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
            // second param
            this.campaignMockupCatalog = response.data[0]['shrt-campaign-mockup-catalogs'];

            let designMockupTypeId = response.data[0]['shrt-campaign-mockup-catalogs'].map((data) => data.design_mockup_type_id);
            this.campaignService.getMockupTypes().subscribe((response: any) => {
              if (response && response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
                let shrtCampMockupType = response.data.find((data) => data.id == designMockupTypeId);
                // first param
                this.campaignMockupTypes = shrtCampMockupType['shrt-campaign-mockup-type'].map((data) => data);
              }
            });
          }
        })
      }
    })
```